# Enumeration in every entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model

According to Eric's definition of entities: *"An object that is not fundamentally defined by its attributes, but rather by a thread of continuity and identity"*

Does that mean apart from all the attributes every entity should also have some sort of status enumeration in them?

e.g. `Order` entity going to have `OrderStatus`, `Task` entity going to have `TaskStatus`, `RequestForm` entity going to have `ApplicationStatus`, etc

Does it mean every entity should have some sort of enumeration (point to the current state of the entity in the lifecycle) in them?

If not then how we are going to know at which stage the entity is in?

***Edit: I said Enumeration as an example. It could be a `string`, `Int`, multiple `boolean` etc.***

***Edit: Further clarification to my previous edit. I meant, to keep track of the entity's lifecycle it could be any other variable of type `string`, `Int`, multiple `boolean`, `enum` etc.***

Comment: What makes you think entities must have different, enumerable states over their lifetime?

Comment: @DocBrown I said enumeration because an entity has to have a lifecycle. So, for example, an Order might have `enum` named `OrderStatus` which has `Placed, Shipped, Delivered`. If an entity has to have a lifecycle then there should be a variable keeping the state of this enum to know at which state the entity is currently in i.e. `Placed, Shipped` or `Delivered`.

Comment: Your edit makes it even more unclear what you mean. The literal answer to your question is now: yes, every entity will have one or more attributes, often a string, an int, a boolean or some other primitve type. That's triviality. I guess what you really mean is *"does every entity require **mutable** properties"* or *can entities be immutable*. This Q&A  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223529/ddd-can-immutable-objects-also-be-entities from 2014 should answer this.

Comment: ... a clarification to my former comment would be really nice.

Comment: Just repeating what you formerly wrote is not "clarification". I asked you specificially if your question is about **mutable** properties, which you did not answer. And I told you how absurd your wording sounds, still you repeated it again. If your question is about mutability, then strip "enumeration" out of it and ask about mutable properties in general. If you mean something different, then I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Eric Evans' definition only focuses on the difference between entities and *value objects*. It doesn't imply anything else. Entities are something that conceptually has some sort of a persistent ID (that may outlive a session in your application). If you have two instances, you determine equality by that ID, and then resolve any conflicts in terms of other properties if they don't match. Value objects are things where you consider two instances to be the same only if all of their properties are equal (no ID needed), and you don't care which instance (of the two) you're working with. 1/2

Comment: Value objects are things like ints, or (x, y) coordinates, or dates, or statuses - any type (simple or composite) where the exact value is the primary thing that determines equality (identity). Now, whether or not you need to track some state of an entity during its lifecycle is a completely separate issue and depends on what your entity represents. If there are stages in its lifecycle that you want to track, then you add a property to track that (note that such a property is likely to be a value object). 2/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be answered by counter-example, specifically in many applications created using DDD a person/customer would be considered an Entity.

I can see how your business requirements may lead you to associating a state to a `Customer` (Prospect, Quoted, Signed, ...), however you could also say that such statuses are more appropriately applied to an `Order` (typically associated with the customer). Therefore I think it is quite likely that a customer may not have a state that changes over time (at least some business requirements may not require such a state). If `Customer` isn't a good example, you can probably find a different Entity such as `Address` that may not have a changing state that needs to be represented as an Enum.

> If not then how we are going to know at which stage the entity is in?

Okay, so lets refine your question to Entities that have a clearly enumerable set of states - it may make sense to represent this as a enumeration, or under closer inspection you may choose a different representation, for example a set of boolean flags (with checks to ensure only valid combinations are allowed).

Another possibility, may be that the current state of an entity is the status an associated `Event` entity - or perhaps there is more detailed logic that only certain states correspond to events - in short the representation does not require a simple enum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't mean `Enumeration` as the only way to keep track of an entity's lifecycle.  I mean there have to be some `boolean`, `enum`, or `strings` to keep track of an entity's lifecycle?

Answer (score 6):

That's not what "continuity" is about here. The point is that an object can be distinguished from another object, *even if their domain attributes are identical*, when this is necessary.

For instance, if your objects model taxi cabs, they will pick up and drop passengers over and over, essentially having only two different states. For normal purposes (ordering a cab) it's enough to know their attributes to decide which taxi to send (speed, model, capacity etc.). But if a customer turns up saying "I lost my important briefcase in the taxi that brought me to the airport yesterday", it's not enough to know that it was *a* Sedan; you have to know *which specific Sedan in your fleet* took the job.

A class that allows this kind of distinction supports "identity" in the sense of the quote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You said "object can be distinguished from another object" That's why we put ID right to distinguish between another object? Eric said "thread of continuity and identity". Identity part I understand. Also, every definition I read it talks about having a lifecycle. I'm just confused about the lifecycle.

Comment: @VarunRaj the life of an domain entity starts when your system first models some thing in the domain, and can end once your system is done with modelling that thing.